# IsSystemObject attribute of smo

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I am getting list of stored procedures from database by using SMO. I have foreach loop over stored procedures to make my intended operatioans on them. However I need to use only user created stored procedures. I use IsSystemObject attribute of stored procedures. However it is so much slow:

Approximately 10 sec:

```
foreach (StoredProcedure mystr in mydb.StoredProcedures)
{
    if (!mystr.IsSystemObject)
    {
        classGenerated += mystr.Name + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

Less then 1 sec:

```
foreach (StoredProcedure mystr in mydb.StoredProcedures)
{    
    classGenerated += mystr.Name + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Is this difference normal for only one if condition? If not, what is the cause of this performance difference? I can use another way to differentiate the system and non-system objects, if there is another method.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yep. And here's why. SMO prefetches certain properties by default and leaves the others as just in time. So, you essentially get a call per procedure to find out if it's a system procedure or not. Luckily, there a fix. Check out [this BOL article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms210395.aspx)

> SMO optimization allows only the minimum properties to be loaded when
>   an object is created. When uninitialized properties are accessed, SMO
>   makes individual requests to load the information from the instance of
>   SQL Server. You can use this method to adjust which properties are
>   initialized for an object when it is first created to further optimize
>   performance

Comment: Yes, it worked. I have changed the VB syntax to C#. For other users here is the better usage:  
**myserver.GetDefaultInitFields(typeof(StoredProcedure));
                    myserver.SetDefaultInitFields(typeof(StoredProcedure), "IsSystemObject");**

Comment: The link is not showing VB so here is what I used: myserver.SetDefaultInitFields(GetType(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.StoredProcedure), "IsSystemObject")

Comment: I'm not a VB guy, but does `GetType(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.StoredP‌​rocedure)` return the StoredProcedure type correctly?