# Missing smo assembly reference

Tags: c#, sql-server, powershell

I'm attempting to instantiate an object from a C# type in my PowerShell script and encountering an error: 'The type or namespace name 'SqlServer' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)' However, using only PowerShell, like:

```
$srv = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server $destinationcomputer
```

works just fine. How do I add an assembly reference in the C# snippet above?
the code:

```
$code = @"
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server;

namespace DatabaseInfoRetrieval
{
    public class DatabaseInfo
{
    public string DbName { get; set; }
    public bool Encrypted { get; set; }
    public double DbSize { get; set; }
    public double LogSize { get; set; }
}

public class DatabaseInfoRetriever
{
    public static List<DatabaseInfo> GetDatabaseInfo(string serverInstance)
    {
        List<DatabaseInfo> databaseList = new List<DatabaseInfo>();
        Server srv = new Server(serverInstance);

        foreach (Database db in srv.Databases)
        {
            if (!db.IsSystemObject)
            {
                DatabaseInfo info = new DatabaseInfo
                {
                    DbName = db.Name,
                    Encrypted = db.EncryptionEnabled,
                    DbSize = db.DataSpaceUsage / (1024.0 * 1024.0),
                    LogSize = db.LogFiles.Size / (1024.0 * 1024.0)
                };

                databaseList.Add(info);
            }
        }

        return databaseList;
    }
}
}
"@
try {
# Load the DatabaseInfoRetrieval DLL
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -Language CSharp 
$sourcecomputer = "s-sql-p063-17.ads.schwarz"
# The empty hashtable for the output
$table = @{
    result     = ""
    definition = "DB-Migration, get DBs from SQL Instance: $sourcecomputer"
}

# Call the C# routine to get database information
$db = New-Object -TypeName DatabaseInfoRetriever
$databaseList = 
[DatabaseInfoRetrieval.DatabaseInfoRetriever]::GetDatabaseInfo($sourcecomputer)

$table.result = $databaseList
# Report success
ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3 -InputObject $table
}
catch {
$table.result = "Error."
$table.errors = $Error[0].Exception.Message
ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $table
}
```

Comment: `Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -ReferencedAssemblies Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server`

Comment: I get an error:
Add-Type : (0) : Metadata file 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server.dll' could not be found

Comment: my bad, `Smo.Server` is just a class, you need to `Add-Type .... -ReferencedAssemblies ([Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server].Assembly.Location)`. your `using` statement is also wrong, `using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server;` should be the Namespace not the class, `using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;`

Comment: I'm lost..can you please  write what the using xxxxx statements should like?

Comment: sure but you have a typo in your code and is unclear what you meant, `LogSize = db.LogFiles.Size`, did you mean `LogSize = db.Size` ?

Comment: that's right, but the main problem is to load the assembly : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO. I can't find it on my system, I'm just using (in PowerShell): import-module sqlsrver

Comment: The assembly is called `Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects`, is possible that just `Import-Module SqlServer` loads it automatically, if not you will need to find out where that assembly is

Comment: Why not keep everything in either one language

Comment: I am attempting to create a DLL written in C# with the hope of achieving better performance. Currently, I am looping over 500 databases on a SQL Server instance, extracting information such as size, etc. Unfortunately, using only PowerShell does not provide the desired level of performance. That's why.

Comment: @Purclot - I doubt that it's powershell slowing you down but rather that SMO has default properties that it fetches eagerly and others lazily. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20740561/issystemobject-attribute-of-smo/20743528#20743528) for a workaround. Also, fwiw, `db.LogFiles` is a collection so I don't think `db.LogFiles.Size` is going to do what you want it to in the general case (i.e. if the database has more than one log file). I know *your* environment doesn't have such anomalies, but may as well account for it.

Comment: @BenThul Does it mean that, considering the fact that both C# and PowerShell are using .NET, there is no significant difference in performance between the languages? It's hard to believe, knowing that C# is a compiled language?

Comment: I'm saying that I strongly suspect that SMO is the bottleneck here. While you're correct that C# is (generally) going to be faster than powershell, I can't imagine that that's going to be substantial in this case where the code that you're writing is really just a wrapper around an external library. But [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). And once you do, let me know; I'm curious to see how it goes!

Comment: if the above is the only thing you're extracting, i'm pretty sure you can beat the performance of SMO by just doing some selects against the raw sys.databases, sys.filegroups, sys.sysfiles and sys.dm_db_file_space_usage system views